# Passing value from one textbox to another in ASP.Net Gridview

Tags: c#

I have two fields in the GridView
1. Notification Date
2. Effective Date

When user entered/change date in the Notification date, I would like to add 10 addtional  days in the Notification date value and auto populate in the effective date every time when user change the notification date. Please advise:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" 
DataKeyNames="ID"
DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1"
OnDataBound="DetailsView_OnDataBound">
<Fields>  

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notification Date">
<HeaderTemplate><span style="color:Red;">*</span> Notification Date  </HeaderTemplate>
<InsertItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNotificationDate" runat="server" Width="150" Text=""    />
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtNotificationDate" PopupPosition="Right"/>
</InsertItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNotificationDate" runat="server" Width="150" Text='<%# Eval("NotificationDate", "{0:d}") %>' />
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtNotificationDate" PopupPosition="Right"/>
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Effective Date">       
<InsertItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEffectiveDate" runat="server" Width="150" Text=""    />
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEffectiveDate" PopupPosition="Right"/>
</InsertItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEffectiveDate" runat="server" Width="150" Text='<%# Eval("EffectiveDate", "{0:d}") %>' />
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEffectiveDate" PopupPosition="Right"/>
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

</Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you married to using the AjaxControlToolkit? Have you considered jqueryui? If you set up the fields as a [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), you can listen to the [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event of the 1st box and update the 2nd one accordingly.

**Update**
The CalendarExtender probably works the same way as the datepicker. If you want immediate updates to show, you'll need to use javascript. You'll still need to listen on the change event.

Comment: Do we have other way based on the code I posted above otherwise I have to change on all the places in the project. Please advise.

Comment: I tried to use OnClientDateSelectionchanged with CalendarExtender but I am not sure how to read the textbox value and update the second textbox. Please advise or provide example if you can. Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to jquery?